# Fluent Nhibernate and DynamicUpdate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have NH mapping

```
public class TblContentMap : ClassMap<TblContent> {

        public TblContentMap() {
            Table("tbl_content");
            DynamicUpdate();

            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
....
            Map(x => x.ArticleType).Column("article_type").Not.Nullable();

        }
    }
```

then in my controller its mapped as

```
public ActionResult Save(TblContent model)
```

But when i call flush it throw exception.
not-null property references a null or transient value  SocialDB.NDbModel.TblContent.ArticleType

Question is why? as i understand dynamic update should track which property was changed and update only that values.

PS. I know that it works if firstly get then update model
var item = MvcApplication.CurrentSession.GetContentById(model.Id);
item.Content = model.Content.StripHtml(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it works as in EF, to use dynamic update need to select item and  update fields then push it to database so it will update only modified fields.

Answer (score 2):

DynamicUpdate is for update only, not inserting new objects.

NH is already telling you what the problem is

> not-null property references a null or transient value SocialDB.NDbModel.TblContent.ArticleType

set the ArticleType property to some value before saving.